# Tutorial tf-nightly not woring

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am pretty new to tensorflow and right now I'm following the tutorials on their website to learn more about it. While going through the text classification one, whenever I get to step that wants me to do:

```
**batch_size = 32
seed = 42
raw_train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'aclImdb/train', 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    validation_split=0.2, 
    subset='training', 
    seed=seed)**
```

I get an error saying AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.preprocessing' has no attribute 'text_dataset_from_directory'. I looked online and it seems that the problem is that tf-nightly isn't installed. But I already installed tf-nightly on my anaconda prompt. Is there another issue I'm missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the package named `keras-preprocessing` is missing in `Anaconda` in your Machine.

You could install it by running the below command in the cell of `Jupyter Notebook`,

```
!pip install keras_preprocessing
```

As I could successfully execute the code in my **`Jupyter Notebook`**, I will share the packages which I have, that may be useful to you in executing **`Tensorflow`** Code.

Please find the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]